# xcode reloading tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

In my app I have a tableview being filled by values from an NSMutableArray. This mutable array is being added to in a separate viewcontroller, and so I have to reload the data.

This is probably a very simple question, but I have reading 15+ posts and none of them seem to address xcode 4.2, and where exactly to put the [self.tableView reloadData]. Where exactly should this method be put? When I have tried putting it in various places in the tableviews source code, the tableview initialized for the first time with no values in it.

Or should it be put in the other viewcontrollers code, in which case how can I reference the particular instance of my UItableview subclass that is being used?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about Xcode 4.2 that should make any difference here, so you should pay attention to other sources you have found, even if they refer to other versions of Xcode.

It doesn't have to be `[self.tableView reloadData]` exactly.  You send the table view object the `reloadData` message.  How you access that table view object - through a property on self, through an instance variable, through a property in another class, etc. - is up to you.

If you already have the `tableView` property set up, then the simplest way of reloading the data from another view controller is to simply send the table view object the `reloadData` message directly.  So, for example, if a method in `ViewControllerFoo` has a pointer to `ViewControllerBar` called `bar` and knows it should reload its table view, it could call `[bar.tableView reloadData]`.

If you don't have the property set up, you can create it yourself, or you could create a `reloadData` method on the view controller holding the table view that does it on behalf of other view controllers.

However these approaches mix up logic and presentation, which is usually a pretty poor architecture.  If one view controller knows that another view controller should be updating its view, then chances are, you should be factoring out some of that logic to a third class that is independent of any particular view controller.  That third class can transmit notifications, or your view controllers can listen for changes to its state via KVO.

Answer (score 0):

after you do [tableView reloadData];

tableView will reload and delegate function to get the table content

if you [tableView reloadData] clear your table

then check the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

you must read the wrong value there

Comment: thanks very much for the response. But I'm still unclear where exactly to place the reload method in my code. When I put it in [viewDidLoad], my tableview seemed to completely bypass the two methods you mentioned.

Comment: Are your table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a navigation controller? Is the view controller that populates the array data pushed ontop of the table view? If so put the reloadData call in viewwillappear because this does get called when a subview of the navigation controller is popped off and the table view is now visible again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your array is correctly implemented. Try to log it when you enter in the view, for example in the method -viewWillAppear.

Usually you put the `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `-viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

You typically call reloadData in the "viewDidLoad" method of the viewController that is set as the dataSource and delegate of the tableView. But it does not really matter much, just make sure you call reloadData every time after changes to the datamodel (your NSMutableArray).

Judging from your description, the reloadData is not the likely cause of your problem. Check that you have set your viewController as the dataSource property of the tableView.

Also, you typically use a data source, as I have assumed here, rather than subclassing the TableView, as you seem to be doing.